# Combining multiple docker images

Tags: docker

I think I might have some misconceptions about how to run docker.
So far I had a server and a script to run multiple docker images.

Now I would like to have a single docker image that contains all of that, but I'm running into some issues.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM prom/prometheus:latest AS prometheus
FROM bitnami/node-exporter:latest as node-exporter
FROM prom/pushgateway:latest AS pushgateway
FROM bitnami/alertmanager:latest AS alert-manager

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .


CMD ["sh","/app/start.sh"]
```

Now I figured that I can just include them in my Docker file and run all of that from a shell script as I did before:

**start.sh :**

```
docker run \
    --name prometheus \
    -d \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -p 9090:9090 \
    -v $(pwd)/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
    -v $(pwd)/prometheus-alerting.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus-alerting.yml \
    prom/prometheus #2>/dev/null
docker run \
    -d \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -p 9100:9100 \
    --name node-exporter \
    bitnami/node-exporter:latest

docker run \
    --name prometheus-push \
    -d \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -p 9091:9091 \
    prom/pushgateway
docker run \
    --name alertmanager \
    -d \
    --restart unless-stopped \
    -p 9093:9093 \
    -v $(pwd)/alertmanager/config.yml:/opt/bitnami/alertmanager/conf/config.yml \
    bitnami/alertmanager:latest
```

Well now I realise that this is something completely wrong as I am trying to run docker images from within a docker image.
What am I missing in my comprehension of this? There is probably something quite different I need to do.

Comment: Is there any reason that you need to combine all your docker images? Unless the programs must be in the same docker I would recommend you have each docker communicate with each-other through ports & API's. Then you can orchestrate all the separate containers with Kubernetes or Docker-Compose

Comment: Well I have a Portainer service running that is hosting all the images. I felt like combining them together would make more sense not to clutter the stack with so many containers.

Comment: You should separate them all and if all containers need to be scaled linearly I recommend putting them in the same Kubernetes pod and orchestrating from there. 

If your headstrong at combining them all still then you can copy specific directories with this command:
COPY --from=<to_copy_name> <dir_in_to_copy_name_abs_path> <abs_path_in_new_docker>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With what you afforded as next, in fact you are using [multi-stage-build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), but only the last image will be act as the base image of final produced image. The final produced image won't have anything which in the former 3 images, unless you explicitly copy things to the last stage. So this definitely won't meet your requirement:

```
FROM prom/prometheus:latest AS prometheus
FROM bitnami/node-exporter:latest as node-exporter
FROM prom/pushgateway:latest AS pushgateway
FROM bitnami/alertmanager:latest AS alert-manager
```

**In fact**, what you are seeking is not the philosophy of docker. See [Multi container apps](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/07_multi_container/):

> Up to this point, we have been working with single container apps. But, we now want to add MySQL to the application stack. The following question often arises - “Where will MySQL run? Install it in the same container or run it separately?” In general, **each container should do one thing and do it well.** A few reasons:
>
> - There’s a good chance you’d have to scale APIs and front-ends differently than databases
> - Separate containers let you version and update versions in isolation
> - While you may use a container for the database locally, you may want to use a managed service for the database in production. You don’t want to ship your database engine with your app then.
> - Running multiple processes will require a process manager (the container only starts one process), which adds complexity to container startup/shutdown
>
> And there are more reasons. So, we will update our application to work like this:
>
> [image]

From above, docker suggest you to deploy different separate application to different containers. So, what you tried with your `start.sh` is OK with docker philosophy, you can't combine different images together with any straightforward way.

Additional, you could use `docker-compose` or `k8s` to improve the way to deploy these containers, of course this could be another topic.

Comment: This is totally correct; combining multiple docker images could result in different libraries that should be isolated stepping on one another's toes - a problem that makes you want to slam your head on the keyboard. Here is my upvote!

Comment: Thank you. I read upon compose and it seems that it would work. Now I just need to figure out how it works.

Comment: So at the end I made a Dockerfile that creates multiple images with my configuration files included. And then use composer to deploy them on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not be combining Dockers to build a monolith Docker -- you could have different libraries that should be isolated stepping on each others toes -- this is very hard to debug in my experience as you have to dive into problems that usually are caused by linux C libraries.

If all the Docker's scale linearly to one another, I recommend you put them all in a Kubernetes Pod to simplify management.

If you are still headstrong on combining these dockers into one docker (HIGHLY DISAGREE -- but I ain't your dad) I would recommend copying the specific directories you need from each docker into the singular docker with this command in your docker script.

```
COPY --from=<to_copy_name> <dir_in_to_copy_name_abs_path> <abs_path_in_new_docker>
```